# How to set api json data to react-select default value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I want to set API JSON data to `react-select` default values

```
const [tag, setTag] = useState([])
const [tag_data, setTagData] = useState([[]]);
```

`useEffect` function for call API and get the JSON data

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const tag_result = await axios(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/tag`);
            setTagData(tag_result.data);
        })();
    }, []);
```

Below is my API JSON data response

```
{id: 1, content_tag: 'Test'}
{id: 2, content_tag: 'test 1'}
{id: 3, content_tag: 'test 2'}
{id: 4, content_tag: 'test 3'}
```

```
<Select
    id="react-select-tag"
    isMulti
    options={tag_data}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.content_tag}
    getOptionValue={(option) => option.content_tag}
    // value={tag_data[0]}  This set the value but after that i am not able to change another tag
    // value={tag} This changed another tag but not set defaultvalue
    onChange={(e) => setTag(e)}
    defaultValue={tag_data[0]} //This changed another tag but not set defaultvalue
/>
```

Comment: can you try with defaultValue={tag_data[0]. content_tag}

Comment: Tried but Not Working

Comment: @KaranChaudhari which of those objects should be the default value?

Comment: value inside tag_data

Comment: @KaranChaudhari Got it. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the state to set a default value after fetching the options:

[image: Edit competent-lalande-hgs1g]

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
const [tagsData, setTagsData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { data } = await axios(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/tag`);
            setTagsData(data);
            setTags([data[0]]);
        })();
    }, []);

<Select
    id="react-select-tag"
    isMulti
    options={tagsData}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.content_tag}
    getOptionValue={(option) => option.id} // using id as it is unique
    value={tags}
    onChange={(selected) => setTags(selected)}
/>
```

I renamed a few variables

Comment: is working now thanks